# What are exactly the Keyword list's thresholds - Pocketsphinx

Tags: keyword, threshold, pocketsphinx

I have been developing a program with Pocketsphinx and i have a keyword list.
I know that a threshold is between 1 and 1e-x with x up until 50 and bigger the word x should increase, but what exactly is that threshold? I can't find anything on Internet explaining that concept.